# How to add all Strings to a ArrayList from a List of objects most efficient?

Tags: java, jpa

NB: Please edit the title if you could write it better.. I've no idea how to explain it better..

Over to the problem:
I'm using autocomplete in a javafx form and need to get all the customers firstName into a list for Strings. I've used JPA to get all of the customers from the database. So i'm a bit worried about the speed of my code.. You see why..

Code example:

```
public static List<String> getAllFirstNamesCustomer() {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Customer c : CustomerBean.getAllCustomers()) {
            names.add(c.getCName());
        }
        List<String> output =
            new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(names));
        return output;

    }
```

EDIT:

Think i found a better way:

```
public static List<String> getAllFirstNamesCustomer() {
    return em.createNativeQuery("select DISTINCT cname from customer").getResultList();  
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about duplicates, I might start with `Set` instead of an `ArrayList`, if possible, I'd have the JPA query try and remove the duplicates if possible. I would not worry "too" much unless it becomes a bottleneck, premature optimisation can be time killer

Comment: 2 questions. 1)why are you extra output list for return? 2) if you want to use output use like this List<String> output=new ArrayList<>(names);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good option would be for the  database driver to stream the data.
A workaround and with a larger customer data set, you can leverage `Java 8's`parallel streams which takes advantage of all cores of the CPU, with one liner

```
List<String> names = CustomerBean.getAllCustomers().parallelStream().map(c.getCName()).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Glad I could help